# input type search - how to get placeholder and clear button in white color?

Tags: html, css, input

in the example below how to get `placeholder` and `clear button` - in white color?

Thanks.

```css
.searcha{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  padding:3px 9px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:1rem;
  letter-spacing:0.5px;
  background:#006790;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<input type='search' class='searcha' placeholder='&#x1F50D;'>
```

Comment: What's clear button? You can use placeholder selector - https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/

Comment: @Dom, clear button is a small `x` on the right  - to clear input

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
.searcha {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px 9px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  background: #006790;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type='search' class='searcha' placeholder='&#x1F50D; Placeholder'>
```

Comment: thanks. what about clear button - a small `x` on the right?

Comment: try `background:white` and you'll see